# Need an example of workflow that aren’t possible in centralized systems, such as hierarchical models

Tags: git

I am reading this [article](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control)

At the bottom of the page it reads (it explains about benefit of a distributed version control system):

> Furthermore, many of these systems deal pretty well with having
>   several remote repositories they can work with, so you can collaborate
>   with different groups of people in different ways simultaneously
>   within the same project. This allows you to set up several types of
>   workflows that aren’t possible in centralized systems, such as
>   hierarchical models.

**What is an example of such a workflow (that aren’t possible in centralized systems, such as hierarchical models)?**

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows

Answer (score 2):

For example on Github if users want to collaborate on an open source project, they can fork the project and clone it, then they will work on their fork instead of creating a lot of branches on the open source project.

Comment: 1) Is fork like a clone of the repository but on the server? 2) Can forked repository be merged with original repository?

Comment: 1) Yes, and Github keeps track of all forked repositories, you can see who forked your repo.
2) Yes you can create Pull Request on the original repository with changes from your fork and then the author can accept and merge the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Another scenario is presence of multiple servers which need to serve the same code base are located in different networks, each of which need to be synchronized with the others. These servers can be behind firewalls, disallowing access by company policies, located in intranets inaccessible to public sources ( facilities in remote locations with limited or no connectivity, military/government locations etc.).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work on a private fork (because I don't want anybody to snoop around what I'm doing) and you want to have version control. That _ workflow_ (for lack of a better word), can't be replicated with centralized version control.... unless you build yourself a copy of the central repo, of course.